# String normalization in Neo4j Cypher - how to?

Tags: parsing, neo4j, cypher, normalization, text-normalization

**Problem background**: Chinese words consists of characters which are words themselves. I have 3 nodes representing Chinese words each with the attribute *word* having the string-values:
  node (1): "a"
  node (2): "b"
  node (3): "ab"

**Question 1**: Using Cypher starting from node (3), how can I find the nodes (1) and (2) which constitute the string of node (3)?

**Question 2**: If there would be a further node (4): "dabc", how would I find all words of length one that are not part of the graph ("d" and "c" have no nodes)?

I know that I could model the relationships between these nodes explicitly, but I'm wondering whether Cypher is expressive enough to take this burden off my shoulders here.

Comment: Please create a sample graph at http://console.neo4j.org and use the share button to generate a link to your setup.

Answer (score 0):

In general all you've got with the graph database is nodes and relationships, and cypher is good for navigating through relationships to find related nodes.  So I would suggest trying some sample models and seeing what seems to suit your purposes best.  I would not shy away from creating relationships.